# Where is customPHPPathDir set in 4.7.0?

Tags: configuration

This appears to be missing. I can't get CiviCRM to execute custom PHP code.

/CRM/Core/Config/Runtime.php at line 139 references $this->customPHPPathDir but there is no such member variable of this object. Because of this customPHPPathDir is not added to the include path.

The comment on the previous line is FIXME.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to not use that folder anymore (Allen is detailing where you can set it), but to write extensions.

What is usually done is to copy paste an existing php file from the core and alter it to fit your need. However, as the original file is likely to be modified in the core between versions, you will either end up with your modify version that has diverged from the core, or you'll need to apply your changes at every upgrade.

Most of what you need to be changed can usually be done more safely and robust from an extension, using hooks

Comment: Thanks, Xavier. If that's the case, should the documentation for 4.7 be updated to say this feature is no longer supported?

Answer (score 2):

From the menu: *Administer > System Settings > Directories*

The custom PHP directory is the second option from the bottom.  The help text reads:

> Path where site specific PHP code files are stored if any. This
>   directory is searched first if set.

Note the use of `[civicrm.files]` at the start of the other directories on that screen if your custom PHP path is going to live within the file structure of your Civi install.

[image: Custom PHP directory]

Comment: Allen, thanks for the documentation, but I'm reporting a bug. What you're suggesting works in 4.6.3 but 4.7.0. Cheers.

Comment: * not 4.7.0 ...

Comment: I'm probably having the same problem.
I need to add a report, so, following the documentation, I create all the folders & files structure (php, templates, ...) under my "Custom PHP Directory".

But executing the report I obtain the message *"Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM\Report\Form\Event\CostSummary.php' (include_path='C:\localhost" ....." and the variable $this->customPHPPathDir is not set.

In the include_path list my "Custom PHP Directory" is not present.

I' need to create an extension also in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: @marcello did you include [civicrm.files]/ at the start of your custom PHP directory on the above admin screen?

Comment: No I put the full path "C:\localhost\drupal\sites\......\php", also because my report's file are not under "default\files" folder (I'm using drupal).
Should I move the files under "default\files" folder and use [civicrm.files]/ notation? Thanks

Comment: @Allen I did a test after moving the files in a folder under [civicrm.files] and I got the exactly the same message. Behaves as if the "Custom PHP Directory" was not considered in the included path. My Civi version is 4.7.0